# Unable to specify trust store details for cassandra SSL auto config in spring boot 2.4.2

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, cassandra

I have a spring boot(2.4.2) project where I am using spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra. I have enabled SSL through the below property.

spring.data.cassandra.ssl=true

But how can I specify the trust-store details for this version(spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3)? As I don't want to pass the details as JVM arguments.

Comment: In earlier spring-data-cassandra-2.1.2 we used to have CassandraClusterFactoryBean through which we can modify/add properties for cassandra config. But in 3.1.3 I don't find any such class or its alternative.

Comment: In spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.4.2 I don't see any option to specify the trust store location or any other details related to trustStore.